# Ubuntu 19.04 .desktop files not working correctly

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, shortcuts, .desktop, desktop-icons

I used to be able to copy and paste the .desktop files from use/share/applications to my desktop for shortcuts. When I first upgraded to 19.04, I selected the allow launching option on the right click context menu and they worked fine.

However, on one of the most recent updates, my shortcuts got deleted. When trying to add them and selecting allow launching, the shortcut will work but the icon will not change to the correct application and if I log out and back in again, the .desktop files are back to being opened in my text editor.

Is it possible to add .desktop files to the desktop and have them permanently launch-able again with the correct icons displaying as they used to before?
    `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` gives me:

```
total 20 
drwxr-xr-x 5 user user 4096 Apr 18 12:33 . 
drwx------ 3 user user 4096 Jun 25 00:46 .. 
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 Apr 12 12:14 customcorner@eccheng.gitlab.com 
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Apr 18 12:32 custom-hot-corners@janrunx.gmail.com 
drwxrwxr-x 5 user user 4096 Apr 18 12:33 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
```

Comment: This is a problem in 19.04. To test for it, create a new folder on the Desktop called "Work in Progress", using the `Files` app, move your .desktop file into the new folder, and see if it works from there. I'll explain more later, if that works for you.

Comment: @heynnema nope didn't work

Comment: Lets eliminate two other things... log into another user account (create one if you have to) and see if the problem occurs there. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema So I've added the result of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`I also added another user and tried to add a shortcut to desktop. When selecting allow launching, it worked perfectly. So I must have something installed or enabled on my default account

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable the three extensions, restart GNOME Shell (alt-F2, r, enter), and retest. If that doesn't fix the problem, let me know, and I'll put together an answer to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Still happening :/ Not sure what the cause is

Comment: No worries! I will! I know this is such a small thing but it honestly has me clueless what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging into another user account shows us that everything works as expected. That means that something in your original user account is causing the problem.

Troubleshooting involves trying to determine what's causing your problem, and this may take some time/effort. But, I'll try an give you a start with an area where common problems occur.

Common problem areas can be the `~/.local` folder, and `~/.config` folder, and the `~/.cache` folder. We rename these folders, **only one at a time**, log out, log back in, and see if the problem has gone away. Here's a note... most of these folders will get recreated when you log back in.

I'll use the `~/.config` folder as an example, as this is the most difficult to do. Rename this folder to `~/.config.HOLD`. Log out. Log back in. Retest for the problem. If the problem is resolved, then there's something in the `~/.config.HOLD` folder that caused your problem. Now you have to restore files from the `~/.config.HOLD` folder, back into the newly created `~/.config` folder. You do this by dragging files/folders from `~/.config.HOLD` back into `~/.config`, **but NOT REPLACING any existing files/folders that are already in the new `~/.config` folder**. (*This way you'll be able to keep some/all of your application preferences*). Then log out, log in, retest.

The same technique is used for the `~/.local` folder, or any other files/folders in your home directory, excluding the major folders like Documents, Music, Pictures, etc.

Pay close attention to what you're doing, 'cause if you aren't careful, you can make it difficult to log back into your account. I'd leave the **bash** and **profile** and **authority** files alone.

**Update #1:**

If you decide that one of the .HOLD folders did not resolve the problem, to return to the previous configuration, you have to manipulate the new folders and the .HOLD folders this way... using `.config` as an example... **move** the new `.config` folder to `~/Desktop/config.NEW`, **rename** `.config.HOLD` to `.config`, log out, log in, **delete** `~/Desktop/config.NEW`.

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was the `~/.local` folder. Thanks!

Comment: @NiallMitch14 that was quick! Glad it's working.

Comment: @NiallMitch14 remember to finish moving files back into the new `~/.local` folder, as per my instructions.

Comment: This is terrible advice to go messing around with making copies of these folders.  E.g. suppose you go through this and then decide that the change to `~/.config.HOLD` didn't fix things.  Moving the HOLD version back to `~/.config` and then logging out will cause you to permanently lose your original configuration as (presumably) the in-memory config is rewritten to `~/.config` upon logout.  Just happened to me :(

Comment: @EoghanM **You didn't follow my instructions**. In your case, you should have **moved** the new `.config` folder to `~/Desktop/config.NEW`, renamed `.config.HOLD` to `.config`, logged out, log in, delete `~/Desktop/config.NEW`.

Comment: @EoghanM I've updated my answer to reflect situations like yours.

Comment: Hi @heynnema — unless I'm mistaken, the updated instructions you've provided basically describe exactly what I did.  I may be wrong but my hypothesis is that the in-memory config gets written to the `.config` folder upon logout, so for moving these folders around safely, you'd need to perform all the steps while there is no running version of Unity. Also, rather than renaming `.config.HOLD` to `.config`, this should be done as a copy, so that if `.config` gets overwritten, then you've still got the `.HOLD` version (that you want) around for comparison.

Comment: @EoghanM basically, when you rename .config to .config.HOLD, the system creates a new .config folder, and opens the required files in the new .config folder. The reason for the specific steps in my update is to move the .config folder out to the Desktop... along with its currently open files, then rename .config.HOLD to .config, log out and let it close the open files in .config on your Desktop, and then a log in starts up with the original .config folder back in its normal place again. Please remember to vote my answer if you think that all of this was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description makes me suspect that your file with dconf settings has been corrupted somehow. To find out, you may want to try this:

```
cd ~/.config/dconf
mv user user.bak
```

Then relogin and check if it behaves better.

Comment: Still behaves the same way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 from Ubuntu 19.04.  The key problem was that the "Allow launching" menu option was not available after right clicking on the icon on the desktop.

After a lot of searching I found this link
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/10/send-app-shortcut-icons-desktop-in-ubuntu-19-10/.

Basically you just need to open Files and copy your .desktop file to your Desktop folder.  **You cannot copy it directly by dragging onto your desktop.**  Then minimise files and on your Desktop right click on your copied .desktop icon and you should see the "Allow Launching" option.  Once you click on this everything works (or at least it did for me).